# KeyboardAwareScrollView blocking nested scroll view and setState function not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, keyboard, scrollview

```html
<View style={styles.container} keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
<SafeAreaView>
<FlatList/>
<FlatList/>
</SafeAreaView>
</keyboardAwareScrollView>
</View>
```

im trying to have nested scroll view inside keyboardawarescrollview but it seems like i cannot do state update on the flatlist, the nested scroll also doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<View style={styles.container} keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
  <KeyboardAwareScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"> --> will solve the issue
    <SafeAreaView>
      <FlatList/>
      <FlatList/>
    </SafeAreaView>
  </keyboardAwareScrollView>
</View>
```